# Se puede encriptar la fuente de un archivo con md5?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, encriptación, md5

quisiera encriptar mis videos que están en mi servidor y por medio de la base de datos recibir la fuente de esos videos, pero encriptados de manera que un solo usuario pueda tener acceso a ese video, tenía pensado usar md5 para encriptarlo del lado de la base de datos y desencriptarlo en el lado del cliente pero de ahí no sé como podría si en mi servidor la fuente es la original y como llamar el video con una fuente encriptada, no sé si me explico.

Comment: Hay una respuesta en ingles que te podría servir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175154/best-approach-to-encrypt-big-files-with-php

Comment: MD5 no encripta un archivo, genera un hash del mismo para validarlo... no es desencriptable. deberias leer respecto a encriptacion.